# Python 3 - How do I export a csv using csv.reader and use it to join dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv, python-3.7

I just started learning python and added a column to a csv file using csvreader.

The second half I joined data frames and exported to csv.

Both halves of the code work separately as I wrote them for two separate projects

Now I'd like to join them together for one script to run but not sure how or what I'm missing or if there is another way I should do this.

This is what I have so far...

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

## part one open csv and append :

```
import csv
report = open('.csv')
r = csv.reader(report)
row0 = next(r)
row0.append('present')
print (row0)

for item in r:
   item.append('yes')
   print (item)
```

## part two joining dataframes :

```
master_report = ('m1.csv')
weekly_report = ('w1.csv')

m1 = pd.read_csv(master_report)
w1 = pd.read_csv(weekly_report)

dataframes = [m1, w1]

join = pd.concat(dataframes)

print (join)

export_csv = join.to_csv(os.path.expanduser(".csv"),header=False)

print (export_csv)
```

I need to be able to export the file in part one as a csv and then use it as the weekly report in part two so that it can be added to the master report

Comment: If you're operating in pandas, why are you trying to use the `csv` module at all? Is there something about your inputs that prevents you from using `read_csv` throughout?

Comment: This was the first code I've written using pandas so I'm not really sure how to use the read_csv to append the column and write data

Comment: What do you want to do exactly in the first part ? Are you just creating a column called `present` filled by `yes` ?